# jQuery validate fire second method only if first was true

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I got a specific problem. I'm using jQuery validate, and want to set a multiple custom rules on one field the code looks like this

```js
var validate = {
  opt: {
    onkeyup: function(element, event) {
      if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
        return;
      } else {
        validator.element(element);
      }
    },

    rules: {
      'user[password]': {
        method1: {},
        method2: {},
        required: true,
      },
    },
  },
  messages: {}
};

jQuery.validator.addMethod('method1', function(a, b, c) {
  return false;
});
jQuery.validator.addMethod('method2', function(a, b, c) {
  console.log('test');
  return true;
});
```

The problem is the method 2 fires only if method 1 is returning true. Code is an example. Is there any option that's setting behaviour like this. Am I missing something? I got similar code on other page and it works correctly.

Comment: `messages` is supposed to be a sibling of `rules` and `onkeyup`, but yet you have it outside of your `opt` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is the method 2 fires only if method 1 is returning true. Code is an example.

Rules are evaluated per field, **one at a time** *(in the order they are declared, with the exception of `required`)*.

If the field is `required`, then the `required` message will display until something is typed into the field.  Once the field starts getting filled in, the remaining methods will fire in order... the `method1` message will display until that rule is satisfied (returns `true`).  So then `method2` will only fire after `required` and `method1` are satisfied (`true`).

Since your `method1` is always `false`, it will never be satisfied and `method2` will never be evaluated.

> Is there any option that's setting behaviour like this.

No, it's designed like this, and there is no option to turn it off.  Otherwise, you'd have several simultaneous messages showing on one field.

> Am I missing something?

If you need two custom methods to fire simultaneously, then these two rules should be combined into one method.

> I <s>got</s> [have] similar code on other page and it works correctly.

Depends on your definitions of "similar" and "correctly".  If you think two rules are evaluated at the same time, that is impossible.  The code in your OP above 
is working as expected and designed.

Comment: Thanks, I will have it on mind in future. I already put my validation rules in one method and it run smoothly. :)

Comment: @tadkovitz, since I correctly answered your original question, please accept my answer.  Thanks.